# "If..Then" loop to highlight rows

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement, highlight

I have code that loops through a large amount of data, copies any row containing the phrase `Flowing` in column B, and pastes that row into another worksheet. The code is:

```
Sub HighlightFlowingIntervals()

Worksheets("3901").Activate

Dim i As Long
Dim cell As Range
Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("3901")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

For i = 6 To ws1.Range("C17300").End(xlUp).Row
    If ws1.Cells(i, "B").Value = "Flowing" Then ws1.Rows(i).Copy ws2.Rows(ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
Next i

End Sub
```

I now want to use the same structure of the loop, but instead of copying and pasting each row, simply highlight each row that passes the "If..Then" criteria.  I know how to highlight using macro recorder, but don't want to do that unless I have to.  I'm just not sure how to implement highlighting into the loop.

Comment: Show the line that the recorder made to highlight the row.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use conditional formatting?

Comment: @Soulfire, no reason at all.  I'm not super experienced and just looking for any advice.  I've heard to try to avoid using 'Select' etc as much as possible, so I was trying to find another way.  Here's what macro recorder spits out: 

Range("A4:O4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

Comment: @Soulfire, is it possible to use VBA to apply conditional formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use conditional formatting.

1. Select all cells you want to inspect
2. Select "Conditional Formatting..." > "Highlight Cells Rules..." > "Text that contains..."
3. Enter "Flowing"
4. Choose a highlight color
5. Click "OK", and watch the cells that contain your text light up!

Answer (score 0):

You need to split your `then` line

```
Sub Button1_Click()


    Dim i As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("3901")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    With ws1
        For i = 6 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
            If .Cells(i, "B").Value = "Flowing" Then
                .Rows(i).Copy ws2.Rows(ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
                .Range(.Cells(i, "A"), .Cells(i, "D")).Interior.Color = vbYellow
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```